# Visual Studio 2017 15.8.4 doesn't show tooltip on debug

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I updated my Visual Studio Community 2017 to 15.8.4.These are my debug settings in Tools-> Option -> Debugging [image]

I can debug application in other applications like console application , desktop application. I'm not able to debug application in any Xamarin Platforms.
[image]

No data tool-tip shows when I click on the extend button.

Like in the console application.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got fixed in the 15.8.5 version!

See link below for more info concerning the issue.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/311540/debugger-tooltip-does-not-expand-in-xamarinios-deb.html

Happy tooltipping!